# How to get values from ArrayList<String>, using text fields for entering the startValue and EndValue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arraylist

I have an ArrayList "10, 20, 50, 50, 50, 100, 200" and so on... What I want is to enter a start value and end value in two text fields. For example from 50 to 200 and I want to get all values from 50 to 200, including the repeated one.
These are my text fields and what I have tried so far:

```js
var myFunction = function FilteringValues(e) {
  var str = "${first}";
  var first = document.getElementById('firstvalue').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('lastvalue').value;
  return e <= 'first' && e <= 'second';
  var filtered = str.filter(FilteringValues);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p id="demos"></p>
  <p>First value:</p>
  <form:label path="first" id="firstvalue" />
  <form:input path="first" />
  <br/>Last value:
  <br/>
  <form:label path="first" id="lastvalue" />
  <form:input path="first" />
  <br/>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Press</button>
</form>
```

I need to loop through all values between the first chosen and the second chosen and get them all in another array. `${first}` contains my ArrayList.

Comment: [MDN array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Kindly show us what have your tried?

Comment: I combined your code into one snippet. Hopefully this helps others discover your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Possible jQuery solution here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSubmit').on("click", function() {
    var array = [10, 20, 50, 50, 50, 100, 200];
    var newArray = [];
    var firstVal = $('#first').val();
    var lastVal = $('#second').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= firstVal && array[i] <= lastVal) {
        newArray.push(array[i]); // Add to new array            
      }
    }

    // loop through new array and display values
    for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
      alert(newArray[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p50mco7p/1/).